# Count sent and received bytes in Go in an http.Handler ServeHTTP function?

Tags: http, go

How can sent and received bytes be counted from within a `ServeHTTP` function in Go?

The count needs to be relatively accurate. Skipping connection establishment is not ideal, but acceptable. But headers must be included.

It also needs to be fast. Iterating is generally too slow.

The counting itself doesn't need to occur within `ServeHTTP`, as long the count for a given connection can be made available to `ServeHTTP`.

This must also not break HTTPS or HTTP/2.

**Things I've Tried**

It's possible to get a rough, slow estimate of received bytes by iterating over the `Request` headers. This is far too slow, and the Go standard library removes and combines headers, so it's not accurate either.

I tried writing an intercepting `Listener`, which created an internal `tls.Listen` or `net.Listen` Listener, and whose `Accept()` function got a `net.Conn` from the internal Listener's `Accept()`, and then wrapped that in an intercepting `net.Conn` whose `Read` and `Write` functions call the real `net.Conn` and count their reads and writes. It's then possible to make those counts available to the `ServeHTTP` function via mutexed shared variables.

The problem is, the intercepting `Conn` breaks HTTP/2, because Go's internal libraries cast the `net.Conn` as a `*tls.Conn` (e.g. https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L1730), and it doesn't appear possible in Go to wrap the object while still making that cast succeed (if it is, it would solve this problem).

Counting sent bytes can be done relatively accurately by counting what is written to the `ResponseWriter`. Counting received bytes in the HTTP body is also achievable, via `Request.Body`. The critical issue here appears to be quickly and accurately counting request header bytes. Though again, also counting connection establishment bytes would be ideal.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: When it comes to measuring TLS traffic bytes, are you wanting the actual network traffic, or are you wanting a count of the bytes after they're decrypted?

Comment: Network traffic would be ideal, but if that's not possible, decrypted bytes is better than nothing.

Comment: Network bytes is actually easier - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is possible, but I can't say I've done it. However, based on browsing the stdlib implementation of the HTTP server and TLS listener, I don't see why it shouldn't be possible; the key is wrapping the connection *before* TLS instead of *after*. This also gets you a more accurate count of bytes on the wire, rather than a count of decrypted bytes.

You've already got an intercepting `Listener`, you just need to insert it in the right spot. Rather than passing your `Listener` to `http.Serve` (or wherever you're inserting it), you want to pass it to [`tls.NewListener`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#NewListener) first, which wraps it in the TLS handler, and then pass the result, which will be a TLS listener (making Go's HTTP/2 support happy) into the HTTP server.

Of course, if you want a count of decrypted bytes rather than wire bytes, you may be SOL - wrapping the `net.Conn` just won't get you there. You'll likely have to do the best you can with counting headers & body.

Comment: Let me know if you try this because I'm really curious to know if it works but I don't have the time to set up a whole test while I'm at work...

Comment: Awesome! It works! Code is here, if you want to add it to your answer https://play.golang.org/p/GskaC-WpbO