# Calculate size of Incoming Request as received over the wire

Tags: go, reverse-proxy

I am working on a ReverseProxy based project and I am trying to figure out how to calculate the size of the entire incoming request. i.e. including headers, body & trailers.

Since speed is important, I don't want to calculate it by adding up the various fields of the parsed request, and instead was looking for a way to do it as the Incoming Request is read.

From what I can see, the readRequest function from "request.go" seems to be the most appropriate place to do this, but I am unsure about how to go about modifying this or wrapping this function to also calculate the size.

Comment: I'd rather not reinvent the wheel, if possible. Just looking for a way to add a byte counter to incoming requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this here - [Count sent and received bytes in Go in an http.Handler ServeHTTP function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944378/count-sent-and-received-bytes-in-go-in-an-http-handler-servehttp-function/43944695#43944695)

It can be modified to work in a Reverse Proxy scenario & does exactly what I wanted.

Update: This Github code was also very useful in the final solution. https://github.com/j0hnsmith/connspy

Now I can get the raw data received & sent over the wire when using Golang as a reverse proxy

Hope this helps someone in the future